# Adobe Livecycle set access state for column in dynamic table

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

Hi i am hoping for some help.
Hi there,
I have a form with a dynamic table. I want that one cell (carcost) is default readOnly, when a button is pressed i want that cell to become open. however i can only get it to work on the first row, it will not work with subsequent rows. any advice is appreciated. i have tried:

```
carb.tblcar.Row1[*].carcost.access = "open";
```

and

```
carb.tblcar.Row1.carcost.access = "open";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Livecycle form with [Loop Unlock](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5oB5O-Q1ld2QTViUnBILUdYTjA/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question.

First you need to set: Repeat Row properties
[image: Repeat Row]

Then "Add" button Script:

```
Page1.Table1.Row1.instanceManager.addInstance(true)
```

Unlock button script:

```
TextField1.access = "open";
```

See example in Form Designer:
[working example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5oB5O-Q1ld2TDVaWTdPWnJRWXc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi there. That part I know. The problem I have is I want to have the unlock loop through the entire dynamic table. I am not sure how to make that work.